# Vue.js - How to get the style display attribute “none / block”

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[CodeExample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r0CW.png)
How to get style display value `(none/block)` by using Vue.js?
jsfiddle with an example: https://jsfiddle.net/DevCccc/52xqe8mv/

```
<div id="app">
  {{count}}
  <ul ref="mylist">
    <li v-show="true">1</li>
    <li v-show="true">2</li>
    <li v-show="false">3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

the ideal result should be: count=2
list:
1
2

Comment: hello, what do you mean by get? whant to change element display by clicking?

Comment: I have a list of records showing on the page, and some of them are hidden, and I need to get the count of hidden records.

Comment: Since @9841pratik link is not working: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-vs-v-show, So use v-if instead of v-show

Answer (score 1):

```
this.count = 
     Array.from(this.$refs.mylist.children)
        .filter(item=>item.style.display !== "none")
        .length
```